# Lexical error running PHP sample project

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans

I'm new to netbeans and trying to run PHP todolist sample project. One of the first things to do is to run mysql.sql file to create table named todo. Here is a query :

```
 CREATE TABLE todo (
 `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `priority` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
 `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
      `due_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `last_modified_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 `title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
 `description` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
 `comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
 `status` ENUM('PENDING', 'DONE', 'VOIDED') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci      NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING',
 `deleted` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
 ) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 ALTER TABLE `todo` ADD INDEX (`priority`);
 ALTER TABLE `todo` ADD INDEX (`due_on`);
 ALTER TABLE `todo` ADD INDEX (`status`);
 ALTER TABLE `todo` ADD INDEX (`deleted`);

 -- data
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`,      `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 2, '2011-10-20 11:00:00', '2015-10-20 00:00:00', '2011-10-20      11:00:00', 'Clean the house', 'Clean the whole house, ideally including garden.', NULL,      'PENDING', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 2, '2011-09-02 18:24:00', '2011-10-05 15:00:00', '2011-10-07 08:26:49', 'Cut the lawn', 'Cut the lawn around the house.', NULL, 'PENDING', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
VALUES (NULL, 3, '2011-09-15 09:30:00', '2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2011-10-19 10:25:00', 'Buy a car', 'Choose the best car to buy and simply buy it.', 'New BMW bought.', 'DONE', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 3, '2011-09-27 17:33:00', '2011-11-01 00:00:00', '2011-10-11 13:48:00', 'Open a new bank account', NULL, 'Not needed.', 'VOIDED', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 1, '2010-08-12 08:17:00', '2010-09-01 00:00:00', '2011-10-07 08:06:40', 'Finish all the exams', NULL, NULL, 'DONE', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 2, '2011-10-02 10:38:36', '2011-10-04 12:00:00', '2011-10-03 13:26:48', 'Send a letter to my sister', 'Send a letter to my sister with important information about what needs to be done.', 'Letter not needed, I called her.', 'VOIDED', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 1, '2010-04-07 17:28:52', '2010-07-01 00:00:00', '2010-05-12 11:47:00', 'Book air tickets', 'Book air tickets to Canary Islands, for 3 people.\r\n', '', 'PENDING', 0);
 INSERT INTO `todo` (`id`, `priority`, `created_on`, `last_modified_on`, `due_on`, `title`, `description`, `comment`, `status`, `deleted`)
     VALUES (NULL, 2, '2011-10-07 10:44:47', '2011-11-01 00:00:00', '2011-10-24 10:46:14', 'Pay electricity bills', 'Pay electricity bills for the house.', 'Paid.', 'DONE', 0);
```

But when I right click on file and try to run it it throws an error saying next:

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 2, column 5.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
>   Line 43, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 56, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 57, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 58, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 59, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 62, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 64, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 66, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 68, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 70, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 72, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 74, column 1

Error code -1, SQL state 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "".
Line 76, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 13 error(s) occurred.

Any help would be appreciated as I have no idea what is wrong.. I've tried to change  few things in query but it throws the same error with the same description. It doesn't seem to spot the difference in the query.. Is there CLEAR or BUILD option as in eclipse ..? What am I doing wrong..?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't need "" around the table name, that should get the query running..

Try running this:

```
CREATE TABLE todo (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`priority` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
`created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`due_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`last_modified_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`description` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
`comment` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
`status` ENUM('PENDING', 'DONE', 'VOIDED') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PENDING',
`deleted` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! tried, but no luck it's pointing at the line 2 - 'id' saying the same

Comment: How are you running the query, it runs fine for me in phpMyAdmin and via the CLI...

Edit: Can you also post the entire SQL file, or upload it somewhere so I can take a peak at that?

Comment: It doesnt specify how to run it so I just right clicked on file and run the file...

Comment: What's your dev environment like, are you using WAMP/MAMP or something similar?

Comment: Yeap it's wamp.. Again , that's a first time I'm trying to use it.. So please Be merciful..:)

Comment: No trouble at all!

Try going to http://localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser, you can run the SQL query in there (just click the 'SQL' tab at the top. The code in your first post runs fine in phpMyAdmin. You'd need to create/select your database in phpMyAdmin first obviously.

Comment: Yeap, when I run that in phpmyadmin it works fine! Isn't it suppose to run from netbeans..? I'm confused.. But anyway, it works! Thanks a bunch Tom!!

Comment: I believe that's a reasonably new feature (I believe) and I don't use netbeans so I can't really comment on why it fails, sorry!